# How to handle with different pythons in the computer

Tags: python, arcgis, anaconda

I'm working wit a Windows 7 machine, and I'm a little confuse about how to handle with the different pythons inside my computer. I have at least four different python's installed in my computer: one in the root path (c:/), one inside the Anaconda distribution, another inside the ArcGis and another in the QuantumGis Distribution.

I'm trying to install the liblas package (libLAS-1.6.0.win32.exe (md5)), but while installing it just sees the ArcGis python, but I would like to use it with Anaconda python...

Any idea about how to handle this? Is it possible to use just one python distribution for those softwares?

Comment: You should look into using `virtualenv` to manage different installations.

Comment: 1. [Use `py` (Python launcher), to run python scripts](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher). It can choose the correct python executable depending on the shebang line at the top of a script, command-line options, its configuration. 2. Anaconda distribution has [`conda` command](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/) that allows you to install packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Anaconda, `conda` is a better alternative to virtualenv, as it manages conda packages, which are not limited to just Python packages.  Create a conda environment like

```
conda create -n py3k python=3 anaconda
```

(this will create an environment with Python 3 and all the packages that come with the Anaconda installer).

The `activate` and `deactivate` scripts that come with conda will help manage your PATH in the shell.

Typically, to manage things like ArcGis, you want to install those into a conda environment, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

`virtualenv` is a good solution, as mentioned by @jonrsharpe, but an alternative is to have shortcuts connected to .bat files.  This is only viable if you know which python you wish to use at any given time.

Create a .bat file for each version of python.  I call mine `runpythonxxx.bat`, where `xxx` is some unique identifier.  Here is a sample .bat file (I call this `runpython34_64.bat`):

```
@SET PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Python34_64";C:\Python34_64\Scripts;C:\Python34_64\Tools\Scripts
@SET PYTHONPATH=C:\Python34_64\Lib

@ASSOC .py=Python.File
@ASSOC .pyc=Python.CompiledFile
@ASSOC .pyo=Python.CompiledFile
@ASSOC .pyw=Python.NoConFile

@FTYPE Python.CompiledFile="C:\Python34_64\python.exe" "%%1" %%*
@FTYPE Python.File="C:\Python34_64\python.exe" "%%1" %%*
@FTYPE Python.NoConFile="C:\Python34_64\pythonw.exe" "%%1" %%*
@SET PATHEXT=.py;%PATHEXT%
```

The shortcut for this file has the following target:

```
%comspec% /k "C:/mydir/runpython34_64.bat"
```

Beware that the `.py` file extension association only supports one version at a time - it is a limitation of file association (it is why UNIX #! line is more powerful).

Comment: It's worth noting that on windows, the file association stuff is best replaced by the `py` launcher application, which comes with Python 3.x - it allows you to specifiy the version you want e.g: `py -3 somescript.py` or `py -2.6 someoldscript.py`.